# Segmentation fault error with my minesweeper code in C

Tags: c, minesweeper

So I have been trying to solve this problem where I have to write a code that counts the number of mines that are around a certain point on a imaginary minefield. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(void) {
    int row;
    int col;
    int count;
    int mineCount = 0;
    int i;
    int j;

    // allocating memory

    scanf("%d %d", &row, &col);

    char **m = malloc(sizeof(char* ) * row);

    for(i = 0; i < row; i ++)
    {
        m[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * (col + 1));        //empty minefield
    }

    //planting mines

    for(count = 0; count < row; count ++)
    {
        scanf("%s", m[count]);
    }

    // counting mines

    for(i = 0; i < row; i ++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < (col + 1); j ++)
        {
            if(m[i][j] != 42)
                {
                    if(m[i-1][j] == 42)
                        mineCount += 1;
                    if(m[i+1][j] == 42)
                        mineCount += 1;
                    if(m[i][j+1] == 42)
                        mineCount += 1;
                    if(m[i][j-1] == 42)
                        mineCount += 1;
                    if(mineCount > 0)
                        m[i][j] = mineCount;
                }
        }
    }

    //printing out the minefield

    for(i = 0; i < row; i ++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < col; j ++)
            printf("%c", m[i][j]);

        printf("\n");
    }


    return 0;
}
```

I put '5 5' for the first input, and for the minefield, my input would be something like this:

```
*....
..*..
...*..
.*...
....*
```

at the end though, I get this 'segmentation fault (Core dumped)' error. I have been searching around for answers and found out that this happens when I try to access something that I have no access to. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Plesse post also the stack trace so the error with the line it is appearing

Comment: I would recommend compiling the code with the `-g`  flag and then running the exucutable under a debugger like `gdb`. This will pinpoint what line is causing the segfault.

Comment: [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Comment: `m[i-1][j]` if `i` is `0`, `m[-1][j]`

Comment: As suggested, debugging will really help you know what is causing the problem. One concern I don't get is, if `mineCount` is not > 0, what do you do? If there are no surrounding mines? I feel you are not setting `m[i][j]` for every relevant value of i and j. Also, you are trying to access out of bounds arrays, `m[i+1][j]`, when i = row-1 is invalid

Comment: Your third input is 6 characters long `...*..`

Answer (score 3):

```
if(m[i-1][j] == 42)

if(m[i][j-1] == 42)
```

For these statements you need to have checks if i and j are not 0, otherwise you are accessing invalid memory

Comment: That also applies to `i+1` / `j+1` at the other end of the array.

Answer (score 1):

Third input of `...*.. // 6 char long` will make

```
//planting mines
for(count = 0; count < row; count ++)
{
    scanf("%s", m[count]);
}
```

to buffer overflow and write an extra `.` to out-of-bound memory.

Also, I don't see any `free`, assuming you must have implemented that.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `if(m[i+1][j])`. If i=row-1 this will be equal to row. But as you only allocated row values and the addressing starts at 0 row-1 is the highest value, which you are able to address.
And also at `if (m[i-1][j])` and `if(m[i][j-1])` when i or j is zero respectively.